# Help understanding a step in a proof (could be a typo?)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

I'm reading the companion book of analysis of Korner, My question is
about a step in the proof of theorem 7.12 (second order taylor series)

**Note:**  $f_{12}$ means $(f_{2})_{1}$

**Theorem**

Suppose $\delta > 0$,  $B(0, \delta) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$
and that $f: B(0, \delta)  \rightarrow R$. If $f_1, f_2, f_{11}, f_{12}, f_{22}$ exist in
$B(0, \delta)$  and $f_{11}, f_{12}, f_{22}$ are continuous at $0$ and
$f_1(0) = f_2(0) = f_{11}(0) = f_{12}(0) = f_{22}(0) = 0$, then

$$ f(h, k) / (h^2 + k^2) \to 0 $$ as $(h^2 + k^2)^{1/2} \to 0 $

**Proof:**

If $\epsilon > 0$, the continuity of given partial derivatives at $0$
tell us that  we can find  a $\delta_1(\epsilon)$ such that
$\delta > \delta_1(\epsilon)> 0$  and

$\|f_{11}\|, \|f_{12}\|, \|f_{22}\| \le \epsilon $ if
$(h, k) \in B(0, \delta_1(\epsilon))$

Using the mean value inequality:

$$|f_1(h,k) - f_1(h, 0)| \le \epsilon|k|$$

*(the proof continue...)*

This is my question:

In my understanding the proof is using the fact that $|f_{12}| \le \epsilon$,
but we need in this step $|f_{21}| \le \epsilon$ and this is not
granted. if this is this correct, why?

In fact, using this theorem he show that if $f_{12}$ exist in $B(0,
\delta)$ and $f_{12}$ is continuous at $0$ too,  then $f_{12}(0) = f_{21}(0)$

Comment: Why do you think you need $|f_{yx}|\le\varepsilon$? You need to control the increase of $f_x$ in the $Y$-direction, so you need to control $(f_x)_y=f_{xy}$.

Comment: @GReyes I correct the notation of partial derivatives. the book notation is $f_{12}$ mean $(f_2)_1$.

Comment: I guess then you can prove Clairaut's theorem first to be able to say that $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$. The proof is also based on the MVT.

Comment: @GReyes, I don't think so. He used this theorem to build a second-order Taylor theorem, only making use of these derivatives. Now, if instead of $f12$, you use  $f21$, you can compare two taylor polynomials and get the equality of $f12$ and $f21$. I suspect that maybe there is a typo in the book.